# Controls on keyboard and mouse are messed up

Tags: pc, keyboard, danganronpa-v3-killing-harmony

I recently started playing Danganronpa V3 - Killing Harmony on PC.

First thing I noticed is that when you play on the keyboard/mouse, it's not very responsive, already gave up on it after googling and seeing that I'm not the only one having this problem.

What my actual problem is this:

I live in a country where french keyboards are the most used, so instead of WASD, I use ZQSD. When moving around, selecting truth bullets, going through the menu, the control scheme works just fine.
But when I'm on the second half of Scrum Debate or Armament something (I don't remember the name yet), when I'm supposed to press "Q" or "Z", it always misses either I press <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Q</kbd> for "Q" or <kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>W</kbd> for "Z", so I have to switch on the controller for those parts as a workaround. (I would have used the controller from the beginning if its analog stick didn't drift upwards)

I know it's not because of the responsiveness because I don't miss when I have to press <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd>.

I have already tried to remap my keyboard to use EN localization keyboards by hitting <kbd>Alt + Shift</kbd> but nothing happened.

So, is there a way to make the ZQSD pattern match ingame for those specific game modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a Keyboard remapper .. that changes your keyboard output for all apps so you can change them and use keyboard stickers -i don't know if that available or not- to change your keyboard keys layout .. or u can change the keyboard keys manually by replacing it .. you can find more about the Remapper here : https://lifehacker.com/5883003/the-best-key-remapper-for-windows